# Setting javascript inside of php for Mobfox backfill

Tags: php, javascript, mobile

I'm using Mobfox as my primary ad network for a mobile app, and have identified the spot where I can backfill:

```
if (preg_match('<!--NOAD-->', $contents)){ 
    global $no_ad_availible;
    $no_ad_availible=true;
}
else
{
$no_ad_availible=false;  
}
```

The script I need inside of there is:

```
<img src="http://serve.vdopia.com/adserver/tracker.php?m=ti;ci=3708;ai=11010;chid=9762;ou=rd;rand=[timestamp]" style="height:1px;width:1px;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" />
<script language='javascript' src='http://serve.vdopia.com/adserver/html5/inwapads/?sleepAfter=0;adFormat=banner;ak=acctnumber;version=1.0;cb=[timestamp]'></script>
<noscript><img src="http://serve.vdopia.com/adserver/tracker.php?m=nji;ci=3708;ai=11011;chid=9762;ou=rd;rand=[timestamp]" style="height:1px;width:1px;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" /></noscript>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, both loading the script from a separate file to inserting it in the code, yet nothing appears.

Obviously I'm not much of a programmer, but trying to learn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `echo` the JavaScript and image calls or (even better) temporarily end your PHP... if you simply put them in PHP code, they will be interpreted as PHP.

I can't tell for sure if you want the code to be inserted if $no_ad_available == true or false.  Either way, the same concept would apply, I'm going to assume you want it inserted if true.  You can use:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('<!--NOAD-->', $contents)) { 
    global $no_ad_availible;
    $no_ad_availible=true;
?>
<img src="http://serve.vdopia.com/adserver/tracker.php?m=ti;ci=3708;ai=11010;chid=9762;ou=rd;rand=[timestamp]" style="height:1px;width:1px;position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" /> ...Rest of ad insert code
<?php
} else {
    $no_ad_availible=false;  
}
?>
```

Good luck.